# Any easy way to deal with ConcurrentModificationException in this java game?

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej, concurrentmodification

I was trying to build a simple Rock-Paper-Scissors game in Java. Basically, the idea is that players get eliminated when they make the wrong move. The  final player remaining is the winner.
I am relatively inexperienced and don't know too much. I ran into this ConcurrentModification exception when I ran it. I tried to Google a bit, but didn't get any easy fix. There were discussions about things like iterators which I don't quite know/understand.

I tried it like below-

GameStarter class:

```
public class GameStarter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    RPS g = new RPS();
    g.play();
    }
}
```

RPS class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class RPS
{
   Player p1 = new Player(" A ");
   Player p2 = new Player(" B ");
   Player p3 = new Player(" C ");
   Player p4 = new Player(" D ");
   Player p5 = new Player(" E ");
   ArrayList<Integer> hold =new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ArrayList<Player> active = new ArrayList<Player>();
   {
    active.add(p1);
    active.add(p2);
    active.add(p3);
    active.add(p4);
    active.add(p5);
        }
   public void play()
   {
    int i,j;
    while(active.size()>1)
    {

     for(Player p:active)
    {
    System.out.print("\n Currently active players are: "+p.name+" , ");
    }   
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    for(Player p:active)
    {
    p.rpsThrow();
    hold.add(p.cur);
    }

    if(hold.contains(1) && hold.contains(2) && !hold.contains(3))
    {
    for(Player p: active)
    {
        if(p.cur==1)
        {
        active.remove(p);
        System.out.println("Player "+p.name+" eliminated ");
        }
    }

    }
    if(hold.contains(1) && !hold.contains(2) && hold.contains(3))
    {
    for(Player p: active)
    {
    if(p.cur==3)
        {
        active.remove(p);
        System.out.println("Player "+p.name+" eliminated ");
        }        
    }

    }
    if(!hold.contains(1) && hold.contains(2) && hold.contains(3))
    {
    for(Player p: active)
    {
        if(p.cur==2)
        {
        active.remove(p);
        System.out.println("Player "+p.name+" eliminated ");
        }
    }

    }

    hold.clear();
    try
    {
    Thread.sleep(3500);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
if(active.size()==1)
{
for(Player p:active)
{
System.out.println("\n\n The winner is : \n"+p.name);
}
}


    }
}
```

and Player class:

```
public class Player
{
  String name;
  Integer cur;

  public Player(String n)
  {
    name=n;
   }
   public int rpsThrow()
   {
    int t;
    t=(int)((Math.random()*3)+1);
    cur=t;
    if(t==1)
    {
        System.out.println("\n"+name+" throws : rock");
    }
    else if(t==2)
    {
        System.out.println("\n"+name+" throws : paper");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\n"+name+" throws : scissors");
    }
    return t;    
    }
}
```

Isn't there any easy way to solve this CMException? Please feel free modify my code to solve it.

Comment: Can you post the error? The stacktrace?

Comment: how does one post stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, once you start using an iterator on a Collection (and this type of for loop uses an iterator) you cannot modify the underlying collection until you have finished with the iterator, otherwise you will get a CME. If you want to remove items from a collection you need to use an explicit iterator and uses its remove() method, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> vals = new ArrayList<>();
    vals.add("1"); vals.add("2"); vals.add("3");

    // This throws a CME
    for(String s: vals) {
        if("1".equals(s)) {
            vals.remove(s);
        }
    }

    // This would work
    for(Iterator i = vals.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        if("1".equals(i.next())) {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. "(and this type of for loop uses an iterator) ". Will it work if I change it to a normal for loop?

Comment: You could change it to a "for(int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++)" type loop and remove(i) would work OK, but don't forget indexes and the array size would change when you removed items. You would probably need to do "vals.remove(i--)" to keep things working.

Answer (score 1):

I changed RPS class to this(with normal for):

```
package RockPaperScissors;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class RPS
{
   Player p1 = new Player(" A ");
   Player p2 = new Player(" B ");
   Player p3 = new Player(" C ");
   Player p4 = new Player(" D ");
   Player p5 = new Player(" E ");
   ArrayList<Integer> hold =new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ArrayList<Player> active = new ArrayList<Player>();
   {
    active.add(p1);
    active.add(p2);
    active.add(p3);
    active.add(p4);
    active.add(p5);
        }
   public void play()
   {
    int i,j;
    Player p;
    while(active.size()>1)
    {

     for(i=0;i<active.size();i++)
    {
      p=  active.get(i);
    System.out.print("\n Currently active players are: "+p.name+" , ");
    }   
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<active.size();i++)
    {
      p=  active.get(i);  
    p.rpsThrow();
    hold.add(p.cur);
    }

    if(hold.contains(1) && hold.contains(2) && !hold.contains(3))
    {
    for(i=0;i<active.size();i++)
    {
        p=  active.get(i);  
        if(p.cur==1)
        {
        active.remove(p);
        System.out.println("Player "+p.name+" eliminated ");
        }
    }

    }
    if(hold.contains(1) && !hold.contains(2) && hold.contains(3))
    {
    for(i=0;i<active.size();i++)
    {
        p=  active.get(i);  
    if(p.cur==3)
        {
        active.remove(p);
        System.out.println("Player "+p.name+" eliminated ");
        }        
    }

    }
    if(!hold.contains(1) && hold.contains(2) && hold.contains(3))
    {
     for(i=0;i<active.size();i++)
    {
        p=  active.get(i);  
        if(p.cur==2)
        {
        active.remove(p);
        System.out.println("Player "+p.name+" eliminated ");
        }
    }

    }

    hold.clear();
    try
    {
    Thread.sleep(3500);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
if(active.size()==1)
{
for(i=0;i<active.size();i++)
{
p=  active.get(i);  
System.out.println("\n\n The winner is : \n"+p.name);
}
}


    }
}
```

The RPE is no longer there. Though I must say it is not quite behaving like I expect to it.
I will also try to look into and study iterators. Thanks for all your help.
EDIT:changed the indices with normal for. Now it works like I wanted.

```
package RockPaperScissors;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class RPS
{
   Player p1 = new Player(" A ");
   Player p2 = new Player(" B ");
   Player p3 = new Player(" C ");
   Player p4 = new Player(" D ");
   Player p5 = new Player(" E ");
   ArrayList<Integer> hold =new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ArrayList<Player> active = new ArrayList<Player>();
   {
    active.add(p1);
    active.add(p2);
    active.add(p3);
    active.add(p4);
    active.add(p5);
        }
   public void play()
   {
    int i,j;
    Player p;
    while(active.size()>1)
    {

     for(i=0;i<active.size();i++)
    {
      p=  active.get(i);
    System.out.print("\n Currently active players are: "+p.name+" , ");
    }   
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<active.size();i++)
    {
      p=  active.get(i);  
    p.rpsThrow();
    hold.add(p.cur);
    }

    if(hold.contains(1) && hold.contains(2) && !hold.contains(3))
    {
    for(i=0;i<active.size();i++)
    {
        p=  active.get(i);  
        if(p.cur==1)
        {
        active.remove(p);
        **i=i-1;**
        System.out.println("Player "+p.name+" eliminated ");
        }
    }

    }
    if(hold.contains(1) && !hold.contains(2) && hold.contains(3))
    {
    for(i=0;i<active.size();i++)
    {
        p=  active.get(i);  
    if(p.cur==3)
        {
        active.remove(p);
        i=i-1;
        System.out.println("Player "+p.name+" eliminated ");
        }        
    }

    }
    if(!hold.contains(1) && hold.contains(2) && hold.contains(3))
    {
     for(i=0;i<active.size();i++)
    {
        p=  active.get(i);  
        if(p.cur==2)
        {
        active.remove(p);
        i=i-1;
        System.out.println("Player "+p.name+" eliminated ");
        }
    }

    }

    hold.clear();
    try
    {
    Thread.sleep(3500);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
if(active.size()==1)
{
for(i=0;i<active.size();i++)
{
p=  active.get(i);  
System.out.println("\n\n The winner is : \n"+p.name);
}
}


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `iterator` in your loops, in which you modify the collection you currently iterate over

```
for(Iterator iter = active.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
{
    Player p = (Player)iter.next();
    if(p.cur==1)
    {
    iter.remove();
    System.out.println("Player "+p.name+" eliminated ");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is iterator, exactly? I am not that far yet. Isn't there anything else that can help?

Comment: Here is the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), and [some examples and info](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm) about them.

Comment: @PredragMaric this code will again get same error, as you are still calling remove on active, you need to call it on iterator

Comment: @user3177843 iterator is a way provided in java to iteratate over collections. it has advantage that you can modify iterator without getting concurrency error and your list will be updated

Comment: Iterator does not have a `remove(E)` method

Comment: @SteveKuo Corrected, thanks. Was focused on loop declaration, just copied the rest of the code which resulted in a sloppy answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change active players for loop to an `Iterator`

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is problematic :-

```
for(Player p: active)
{
    if(p.cur==2)
    {
    active.remove(p);
    System.out.println("Player "+p.name+" eliminated ");
    }
}
```

you are iterating on list active and removing the element from it.

You need to use iterator and remove data from iterator, it will remove from actual list automaticallly.

```
  for(Iterator playerIterator = active.iterator(); playerIterator.hasNext();) {
   Player p = (Player)playerIterator.next();
   if(p.cur==2){
    playerIterator.remove();
   System.out.println("Player "+p.name+" eliminated ");
  }
 }
```

Comment: Iterator does not have a `remove(T)` method. It does have a `remove` method.